# In uploading file they show connection is not open how to solve that

Tags: java, exception, ftp

I am working in a java application into that i am using ftp to send file.
but when i send 20-30 file its show exception that is connection is not open
and the file is not send can any one help me. the cade that i am using to uplode file is below

```
public void uploadtxtFile(collectinfo myobj,String localFileFullName, String fileName, String hostDir)
            throws Exception {
       FTPClient ftpclient= DBConnection.connect();
        File file = new File(localFileFullName);
        if (!(file.isDirectory())) {
            if (file.exists()) {
                FileInputStream input = null;
                 BufferedInputStream bis=null;
                try {
                    input = new FileInputStream(new File(localFileFullName));
                    if (input != null) {

                        hostDir = hostDir.replaceAll("//", "/");
                       logger.info("uploading host dir : " + hostDir);


                       boolean bool =false ;


                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 1111"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                 try{
                    ftpclient.setBufferSize(1048576);
                     ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 2222"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                   if(  ftpclient.isConnected()){                   
                    //  here server timeout error is get
                       logger.error("here server timeout error is get");//new
                       bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 3333"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                       bool =  ftpclient.storeFile(hostDir, bis);



                }  else{
                       logger.error("here server timeout error is get");//new
                             bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
                       logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 6666"+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());
                       ftpclient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                       bool =  ftpclient.storeFile(hostDir, bis);


                   }}finally{
                       bis.close();
                    input.close();


                   }

                   logger.error("Replay of the ftp store file is 4444 "+  ftpclient.getReplyCode());

                  if (bool) {
                            logger.info("Success uploading file on host dir :"+hostDir);
                        } else {

                             logger.error("file  not uploaded.");
                             BackgroundService.pendingQueue.add(myobj); 
                        }

                    } else {
                         logger.error("uploading file input null.");
             }
           } catch(Exception ex)
                {
                     logger.error("Error in connection ="+ex);
                    BackgroundService.pendingQueue.add(myobj);

                }finally {
                     ftpclient.logout();
                     ftpclient.disconnect();
              }

            } else {
                  logger.info("uploading file is not exists.");
            }
        }
    }
```

into that DBConnection is a class that return FTPclient obj

Comment: You are closing ftp connection in finally block, are you calling this method multiple times to send 20-30 files?

Comment: so what should i do.If i do not close the connection to they show ftp 421 exception multiple open connection can you tell me where i close the ftp connection

Comment: you should initialize ftpClient object outside this method and it should be once, then use that to send multiple files and once you are done close that ftpClient. I could see `FTPClient ftpclient= DBConnection.connect();` in your method, try to get the connection where you are calling `uploadtxtFile` method

Comment: i try your code but the responce is same

Comment: can you try this [example](http://www.journaldev.com/661/java-ftp-upload-example-using-apache-commons-net-api) it should work.

Comment: If i am stop the application at point when it connected to the server for 3-4 sec so it have a time to establish the connection it may be work or not

Comment: yes i try this example but the show the same response

Comment: how do you call `uploadtxtFile` , can you paste that code?

Comment: public static void uploadfile(collectinfo myobj,String localDirPath, String remoteDirPath) throws Exception {
        //FtpFilesFolderUpload ftpUploader = new FtpFilesFolderUpload(Constants.SERVER_URL, Constants.SERVER_USER, Constants.SERVER_PASSWORD);
          
     FtpFilesFolderUpload ftpUploader = new FtpFilesFolderUpload();
        String path = localDirPath;
        String xmlPath = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String xmlfile = "/" + xmlPath;
        ftpUploader.uploadtxtFile(myobj,localDirPath, xmlfile, remoteDirPath);
     
     
    }